# Is there a way to import GPS height-position data from a navigating vessel in real time to Mathematica?

Tags: data, localization

After reading [this](https://blog.wolfram.com/2009/04/17/mapping-gps-data/), I found that Mathematica could be a useful tool to analyse GPS data from a navigating vessel at sea. But this example is for land-based fixed positions, i.e. the position of a lake on the globe.

Suppose a computer is on a ship, and we want to import the GPS position of the ship into the computer. Then Mathematica has this tool:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindGeoLocation.html

This attempts to  find the current geo location of the computer. But to my knowledge, this position includes only latitude and longitude.

If it does include height-estimation, it may also be that FindGeolocation is inaccurate on height-estimation.

Does Mathematica have a program that can import GPS data from a navigating vessel  with both latitude, longitude and height over sea level?

I would like to import data from a GPS readout into Mathematica in real-time, and wonder therefore if there are specific functionalities in Mathematica to receive data from a GPS and directly feed it into a command line, ie. particular codes that automatize the conversion of GPS data into a regular dataset in the format

```
{{time_1,height over sea level_1}, {t_2,h_2},....{t_n,h_n}}
```

Thanks

Comment: Ok, tried to add some more.

Comment: The docs say: *"`FindGeoLocation` returns a `GeoPosition` object containing `{latitude,longitude}` or `{latitude,longitude,elevation}` or containing `Missing["NotAvailable"]` if it cannot find an explicit geodetic location."*. So if a GPS is available, and not just a location guessed from IP or address, `elevation` *should* be available.  Otherwise, if the GPS can be addressed via a system call, USB or serial interfaces, it will depend on the nature of the calls available and the format they are returned. Do you have a more specific example?

Comment: Yes, consider the ship navigating on a rough sea. Then the elevation of the ship (with the computer with Mathematica installed on board) is oscillating over the sea according to the wave-train. Then take the height-coordinates in real time and prepare them as a set of points on a 2D plot, where x is the time dimension, and y is the amplitude.

Comment: Many GPS devices will export NMEA data to a serial interface. (See, e.g.,: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/gps-basics/reading-gps-data).  

A solution is to open a serial connection (http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/device/Serial.html) and then to write your own function that parses the NMEA string into the input for a `GeoPosition` http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GeoPosition.html

Answer (score 1):

The best way to extract the height from a GPS position is via the command:

```
GeoElevationData[FindGeoLocation[]]
```

This gives the output of the height where the computer is located:

Out12: 10.0 m

Alternatively of the height where the IP address is routed from:

```
 GeoElevationData[FindGeoLocation[ip]]
```

Out13: 82 m